# How can I add a fixed amount of time to all "hh:mm" strings in a document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vim, macros, find-and-replace

I have a document that's a transcription of a video interview. The video itself has embedded SMPTE timecode as well as burnt-in timecode (BITC). The SMPTE timecode and BITC correspond to the time of day the interview was shot, in 24-hour format.

In the transcription document, there are timestamps in square brackets every two minutes, in `[hh:mm]` format. However, these transcription timestamps begin at '00:00'.

Is there a way to use a kind of "Search and Replace" function to go through the document, find all of the instances of `hh:mm` and add a fixed time to those timestamps, thereby reflecting the time of day, matching the SMPTE timecode?

The perfect solution would be a tool that:

1. Finds all timestamps in `[hh:mm]` format
2. Adds the interview start time, "yy:yy" in 24-hour format to all of those original timestamps, "xx:xx."
3. Replaces the timestamps with the new, corrected timestamp, "zz:zz," which would equal xx:xx+yy:yy.

So for instance, if my interview started at 9:30 in the morning, each timestamp would be replaced in the following way:

1. 00:00 + 9:30 = 9:30
2. 00:02 + 9:30 = 9:32
3. 00:04 + 9:30 = 9:34
4. Etc.

Comment: Could you share some more information about the data.  Is all the data stored as strings? Are all the times in one column? Is there non time data in the column?  have you tried anything?

Comment: How do you want wrapping handled .................... **12:54 + 06:14** ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent OP said 24h format, so 12:54 + 06:14 doesn't wrap, it's 19:08.

Comment: Have you tried the macro recorder?

Comment: @gtwebb The timestamps are written into the body of the text paragraphs, separated out by square brackets between words, i.e. `Lorem [00:08] ipsum...`

Comment: @Raystafarian Not yet. Presumably I could carefully use that with "Find and Replace," but will have to make sure that I'm copying and pasting back and forth between Word and Excel, right? I would have to make sure that the "Find and Replace" would skip to the next square bracket, in order, properly. How might you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the best way to do it but here is one solution.  It's obviously not very polished as I'm not sure how you'll be putting in your time increment or if the data is just a paragraph in one cell but it should get you most of the way there.

It splits the active cell value into an array looking for "[" then it adjusted the first 2 characters up by you hour step and characters 4 and 5 by the minute step then puts it all back together.

Also this works on the activecell which isn't very good coding practice.

```
Sub update_times()

    Dim sParts() As String
    Dim input_text As String
    Dim output_text As String
    Dim split_on As String
    Dim hours_add As Integer
    Dim minutes_add As Integer
    Dim hours_final As Integer
    Dim minutes_final As Integer

    split_on = "["
    hours_add = 9
    minutes_add = 30
    input_text = ActiveCell.Value

    sParts = Split(input_text, split_on)
    output_text = sParts(0)

    For i = 1 To UBound(sParts)
        hours_final = Left(sParts(i), 2) + hours_add
        minutes_final = Mid(sParts(i), 4, 2) + minutes_add
        'checks to wrap data
        If minutes_final > 59 Then
            hours_final = hours_final + 1
            minutes_final = minutes_final - 60
        End If
        If hours_final > 23 Then
            hours_final = hours_final - 24
        End If
        'put the part back together with the new hour and minutes
        sParts(i) = "[" & Format(hours_final, "00") & ":" & Format(minutes_final, "00") & Right(sParts(i), Len(sParts(i)) - 5)
        'add the part to the final string
        output_text = output_text & sParts(i)
    Next
    ActiveCell.Value = output_text

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I use this script in OpenOffice?

Comment: No idea, you tagged it as excel so that was what I scripted for. and what I know best.

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking of a macro that might go between Word and Excel, or between OO Writer and OO Calc.